# Google auth redirect_uri no longer authorized even when the same uri is placed in settings

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I'm getting a redirect uri error for google authentication even when I've already placed the EXACT url in the google dev console config settings. Anybody know what could trigger such an error?

Below are screenshots of the error. I have the exact uri authorized in the settings yet trying to authenticate leads to a redirect_uri error!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just figured this out. If you're ever as dumb as me and your google app has multiple client IDs you could be using a different client ID for authorization then the one you're setting your redirect uri to.

When you're changing the redirect uri, check to see if you have another client_id and set the redirect_uri for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out. If you're ever as dumb as me and your google app has multiple client IDs you could be using a different client ID for authorization then the one you're setting your redirect uri to. When you're changing the redirect uri, check to see if you have another client_id and set the redirect_uri for that.